# missing variables have point, need to make it blank

Tags: sas

I have a table and tables shows the missing variable with point as below. Point means it is empty(missing) variable but I don't need to see it

```
 table 
 var
  .
  23
  .
```

and so on. I don't want to see that point. I need completely blank . 
When I do if then statement gives me error.

```
   data tos;
   set tos;
    if TOS.AUTH='.' THEN TOS.AUTH =.;
          ________
          557
```

ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the COMPILATION phase.
ERROR 557-185: Variable TOS is not an object.

How can I delete these points.

Comment: I think those are numeric variables... not char. You cannot do it that way. You should not change the data. But there is an option somewhere to change how missing values are shown when output.

Comment: Your `if` is fine, more or less, but you cannot refer to variables that way.  You just use `if auth=...` not `if tos.auth`.  This won't accomplish anything if `auth` is a numeric variable, although if it is a character variable this could work (`if auth='.' then auth=' ';`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned with how it comes in printed output outside of SAS, you have a few different options depending on how you print it out.  Most common is `options missing=' '` which sets the missing character to space.

Internal to SAS, it really doesn't matter what it looks like, just accept the period is my suggestion.